# Unable to separate rows of a table using react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to **create a table with multiple rows and fixed columns**. Right now I have added two rows with fixed 5 columns.Below is the code.

```
import React from 'react'

class Table extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            columns: [    
                {
                    person1: "Shubham",
                    person2: "Nikhil",
                    person3: "Rishabh",
                    person4: "Piyush",
                    last: <button>Delete</button>
                },
                {
                    person1: "Manish",
                    person2: "Nikhil",
                    person3: "Harsh",
                    person4: "Shashank",
                    last: <button>Delete</button>   
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "table">
                {
                    this.state.columns.map((obj) => {
                        return Object.values(obj).map(
                            (value) => {
                                return value +" "
                            }
                        ) + "\n\n"
                     })
                 }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Table
```

My expected output is :

> Shubham Nikhil Rishabh Piyush (delete button)
>
> Manish Nikhil Harsh Shashank (delete button)

but I am getting:

> Shubham ,Nikhil ,Rishabh ,Piyush ,[object Object] Manish ,Nikhil
>   ,Harsh ,Shashank ,[object Object]

Why "\n" is not working here.  Also notice if I remove all spaces addition to return statement button appears, I couldn't figure why this is happening.

Comment: Why don't you use a real `<table>` with `<tr>` and `<td>` elements?

Comment: trying something new

Comment: What do you expect \n to do? Do you mean to use a `<br/>`?

Comment: Yeah, I expected that  @duhaime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the code below? I dropped the delete keys from your object (as it's duplicated code) and factored the rendering logic a little to simplify. I also added the functionality to delete rows when users click the `delete` button in each row:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.deleteRow = this.deleteRow.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      columns: [
        {
          person1: 'Shubham',
          person2: 'Nikhil',
          person3: 'Rishabh',
          person4: 'Piyush',
        },
        {
          person1: 'Manish',
          person2: 'Nikhil',
          person3: 'Harsh',
          person4: 'Shashank',
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  deleteRow(idx) {
    this.setState({
      columns: this.state.columns.filter((col, colIdx) => colIdx !== idx)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className='table'>
        {this.state.columns.map((obj, idx) => (
          <Row key={idx}
            idx={idx}
            data={obj}
            deleteRow={this.deleteRow} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Row = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {getNames(props.data)}
      <button onClick={props.deleteRow.bind(null, props.idx)}>
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

const getNames = obj => {
  let string = '';
  Object.keys(obj).map((key) => string += obj[key] + ' ')
  return string;
}

export default Table;
```

This renders:

[image]

#### Addendum: Why was your code not working?

Your main rendering logic revolved around the following loop:

```
{
  this.state.columns.map((obj) => {
      return Object.values(obj).map(
          (value) => {
              return value +" "
          }
      ) + "\n\n"
   })
}
```

This can be rewritten more compactly as:

```
{this.state.columns.map((obj) => (
  Object.values(obj).map((value) => value +" ") + "\n\n"
))}
```

Here you examine each object in `this.state.columns`, and for each of those objects, you add the object's values to a string, then add `\n\n` after adding the last value for the object.

There are two problems with this approach. The first problem is that while `\n\n` creates breaking whitespace in other programming paradigms (e.g. when building a string to be displayed in a .txt file), `\n` does not create breaking whitespace in HTML. Breaking whitespace in HTML can be created with a `<br/>` element, or by giving an element `display: block`, or in other ways, but not with `\n`.

The second problem is that the last value in each object within `this.state.columns` is an HTML element, and needs to be handled differently than the raw string content in other values. As @Ankari shows, you can display these button elements by calling `{val}` for each of those values, which will prevent the `[Object,Object]` problem you were seeing at the end of each of your rows.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Can you also answer why my code was failing

Comment: Also I want to add more columns so I used state

Comment: @Nikhil I moved the row data to state and added the onClick events to delete the rows when users click the delete button, so you can see how that works. I also added an explanation why your previous code didn't work -- does this help?

Answer (score 1):

You can let a real HTML table do the job for you. You can keep the data in state and add more data as needed, also have custom buttons as you wish.
You can style the table as you need it to look using css then.

```js
class Table extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            columns: [    
                {
                    person1: "Shubham",
                    person2: "Nikhil",
                    person3: "Rishabh",
                    person4: "Piyush",
                    last: <button>Delete</button>
                },
                {
                    person1: "Manish",
                    person2: "Nikhil",
                    person3: "Harsh",
                    person4: "Shashank",
                    last: <button>Delete</button>   
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.columns.map((column, idx) => (
                <tr key={idx}>
                    {Object.values(column).map((val, idx2) => (
                      <td key={`${idx}-${idx2}`}>{val}</td>
                    ))}
                  </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```